# plugins_url() returns incorrect url

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I use this line of code in my wordpress plugin:

```
jQuery.get(<?php echo plugins_url() . '/FixFormData/getuser.php'; ?>, { q: str }, function(response){
                    var parsed = JSON.parse(response);
                    var arr = [];
                    for(var x in parsed){ arr.push(parsed[x]);}
                    jQuery('#input_1_3').val(arr[1]);
                    jQuery('#input_1_4').val(arr[2]);
            });
```

This line doesn't return the correct url:

```
<?php echo plugins_url() . '/FixFormData/getuser.php'; ?>
```

I get the following error on my website:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

jQuery.get(http://*****.be/wp-content/plugins/FixFormData/getuser
```

I am, however, not missing a ')' anywhere....

When i just use http://*****.be/wp-content/plugins/FixFormData/getuser.php in the jQuery.get, evrything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to put quotes around your URL:

```
jQuery.get("<?php echo plugins_url() . '/FixFormData/getuser.php'; ?>", ...
```

Comment: I tried this before and apparently I made a typo then! Now it works, thank you!